# Copy Drive File With All Permission

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

I use [this Copy method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) for copy file.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/copy
```

But this method copy only files not its permission [means copied file dose not shared with  users of old file]

I need to copy files with it's permission.I checked [permission list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list) method and [permission insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) method. But permission insert Method needs email id and permission list method doesn't give email ids.

Is there any other method to do such thing. I use Python httplib2 lib for send http post and  get method

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible for now, the owner need to explicitly share the copied file again. The way we don't expose email addresses on permissions list is a hot topic and something we'll improve soon.

Comment: If you don't want to expose email addresses. Then another option is provide function like **Clone Copy** which copy file with all permissions  and metadata except ID of that file.

Comment: @ParthGajjar, that was one of the options discussed earlier. Please wait a little bit.

Comment: OK i will wait :P 

but until then i managed this thing with folders through some alternative way.
Thanks